# Launching a java application outside of the sandbox

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

I have an signed jar file with

```
System.setSecurity(null);
```

to run outside of the sandbox. I have a shared MS Access database (not my choice, no way around using a different database) on a shared drive. I continue getting a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyTableModel.setHostURL(MyTableModel.java:279)
```

error from javaws, and cannot figure out why it is not connecting. When i launch the jar file without using the .jnlp file, it launches without a problem. Do i have to include additional options in the jnlp file? I've read the the documents and this website over and over, but cannot figure it out.

(edit, format to mention the actual error)

```
Error: Unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

(/edit)

Below is my jnlp file (i have removed the link paths, etc for security reasons). 
Any help would be great, thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File for NameofFIle -->
<jnlp  spec="6.0+"  codebase="https://link/"  href="filename.jnlp">  

<information>    
<title>filetitle</title>    
<vendor>company</vendor>     
<description>filename</description>    
<description kind="short">description</description>    
<icon href="https://link//icon.png"/>    
<icon kind="splash" href="https://link//splash.gif"/>    
<offline-allowed/>     
<association mime-type="application-x/swingset2-file"  extensions="swingset2"/>     
<shortcut online="false">      
<desktop/>      
<menu submenu="app name"/>    
</shortcut>  
</information>  

<information os="windows">       
<title> app name </title>    
</information>  

<security>      
<all-permissions/> 
</security>  

<resources>    
<j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc"/>    
<jar href="https://link//file.jar"/>  
</resources>  

<application-desc main-class="mainClass"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: 1) A signed Jar file should already be operating 'outside the sandbox', so calling `System.setSecurity(null);` is neither necessary nor sensible (e.g. an applet operating outside the sandbox still cannot call `System.exit(n)` for very good reasons.  But once the code wipes out the remaining `SecurityManager` it can, which can cause problems for other applets operating on the same page!  2) The `NullPointerException` is likely not related to security in any case!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not leave my program with security disabled, that is just an option i tried. The overall fact is that this is a desktop application and I just simply need an auto-updating solution. I suppose since i can't get javaws working for this specific app, i'll try a manual updating method with two jar files. I'll leave javaws for an applet specific or non-database connection app (.. or until i figure out the issue).